# Stop subsequent methods call of onclick

Tags: javascript

If this is problem already existed then please help me mark it as duplicate cause I cannot find the similar solution.

While having multiple methods call on onclick attribute, for example:

```
<a onclick="foo();afterFoo();afterAfterFoo();"/>
```

I want to stop subsequent calls like `afterFoo()` , `afterAfterFoo();` when `foo()` meets some condition.

I tried `return false;` in method `foo()` but it still calls other methods. I remember this trick used to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't happen that way. You need to create a wrapping function and attach it as onClick handler rather than call the 3 functions from it directly. You may call your 3 functions from the wrapping function based on the if conditions.

```
<a onclick="clickHandler();"/>
function clickHandler() {
    foo() && afterFoo() && afterAfterFoo();
}
```

Comment: You can probably use the same syntax that is used in function like
`<a onclick="foo() && afterFoo() && afterAfterFoo();"/>`

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. I use the latter suggestion on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by using `if`conditions:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
  return true;
}

function afterFoo() {
  console.log('afterFoo')
  return false;
}

function afterAfterFoo() {
  console.log('afterAfterFoo')
  return true;
}

function specialSequence() {
  if (foo())
    if (afterFoo())
      afterAfterFoo();
}
```

```html
<a onclick="specialSequence();">Click Me</a>
```

So what happens here:
we are calling `specialSequence`. It runs `foo` and if it returns true, we continue to the next sequence function `afterFoo`, and if this returns true we continue to `afterAfterFoo`. But it returns false, which means that after running `afterFoo` the function `specialSequence` will stop running.

After you stated that there are several parameters to each function and you don't want `specialSequence` to have the sum of parameters of all the functions its using, You can just use it in the html like this (simply copy the function to the `onClick`)

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
  return true;
}

function afterFoo() {
  console.log('afterFoo')
  return false;
}

function afterAfterFoo() {
  console.log('afterAfterFoo')
  return true;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="if (foo())
    if (afterFoo())
      afterAfterFoo();">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Actually there are more parameters for each function, which is provided via Struts and JSP, so it's will make the first method to have more and more parameters on one single method. By the way, I don't want them to nested into each other as they're not always go together
Sorry I should have stated that. Thank you for your help

Comment: @ToanLu I edited my answer, please check if it works for you

Comment: I did go for @Aditya solution, which I think will give the same result as your solution. Thank you for the update, bro!